# Android Calender dates persisting in a array

Tags: android, date, calendar

i Want to store last seven date in a array.Like Today's date is 16-03-2015 so   from that date whatever the last seven date was, i want to store in a array.means i want to get the last seven date from the current date and want to store in a string array.

ex:-Today's date is 2015-03-16;

my expected array {2015-03-15,2015-03-14,2015-03-13,2015-03-12,2015-03-11,2015-03-10,2015-03-09,}.

Array type may be string.

Any help will be appreciable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use the Calendar object.

```
Calendar myCalendar = new Calendar();
myCalendar.set(2015, 3, 16);
```

This is how you set up your calendar. Now you can loop through it and substract days from it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    myCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY, -1);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
    String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime()); 
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

In the for loop you can add the date string to your array.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.

```
 Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    myCalendar.set(myCalendar.getTime().getYear()+1900,myCalendar.getTime().getMonth() , myCalendar.getTime().getDate());
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        myCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()); 
        System.out.println(date);
```